# Building a 6/49 Lotto Ticket Simulation

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I am working on a project for college which models a 6/49 Lotto luck game.

A ticket is created by choosing 6 different numbers from 1 to 49.
I have to simulate 10^6 tickets and compare it with a lucky ticket.
I want to find out the cardinal of the intersection of the 6 numbers of a random ticket and the 6 numbers of the lucky ticket. But if I do it once for the 10^6 tickets, the probability of having a ticket that matches perfectly the lucky ticket is low. So I tried to do this process "nr_esantion" times with 10^6 random new tickets and make an average.

Here is my approach:

```
nr_esantion<-30
es<-10^6
nr_49<-1:49

table_1 <- rep(0,7)
table_1
for(i in 1:nr_esantion)
{
  lucky <- sample(nr_49,6,replace=FALSE)


inters <- replicate(es,length(intersect(sample(nr_49,6,replace=FALSE),lucky)),simplify="array")


aux <- array(table(inters))


# There are situations in which at one step "i", there are no intersections of cardinal 5 or 6.
if(length(aux)==5)
{
  aux <- c(aux,0,0)
}
else{
if(length(aux)==6)
{
  aux <- c(aux,0)
}
}

table_1 <- table_1+aux

}

table_1 <- table_1/nr_esantion
```

I am happy with the results I got but my problem is that one iteration, for $10^6$ tickets, it takes around 20 seconds. So for the total of 30 iterations, it takes around 10 minutes. I have to change the "nr_esantion" to 300 for some of the project tasks.

My question: Is there a faster method to compute these $10^6 * 300$ samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will speed it up by more than an order of magnitude (you can also do this parallel):

```
set.seed(895636177)
nr_esantion <- 30L
es <- 1e6L
nr_49 <- 49L

library(RcppAlgos) # for `permuteSample`

table_1 <- integer(6)

system.time({
  for (i in 1:nr_esantion) {
    lucky <- sample(nr_49, 6)
    table_1 <- table_1 + tabulate(
      rowSums(
        matrix(match(permuteSample(nr_49, 6, n = es), lucky, 0L), es, 6) != 0L
      ), 6
    )
  }
  
  table_1 <- c(nr_esantion*es - sum(table_1), table_1)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   22.00    1.16   24.11

table_1
#> [1] 13079255 12390731  3970451   530064    28966      529        4
```

Or simply sample directly from the hypergeometric distribution:

```
system.time(
  table_2 <- rmultinom(1, nr_esantion*es, dhyper(0:6, 6, nr_49 - 6, 6))
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0
```

Compare the simulations against the exact distribution:

```
data.frame(
  Matches = 0:6,
  Simulation1 = table_1/nr_esantion/es,
  Simulation2 = table_2/nr_esantion/es,
  Exact = dhyper(0:6, 6, nr_49 - 6, 6)
)
#>   Matches  Simulation1  Simulation2        Exact
#> 1       0 4.359752e-01 4.360317e-01 4.359650e-01
#> 2       1 4.130244e-01 4.129101e-01 4.130195e-01
#> 3       2 1.323484e-01 1.324264e-01 1.323780e-01
#> 4       3 1.766880e-02 1.764053e-02 1.765040e-02
#> 5       4 9.655333e-04 9.718000e-04 9.686197e-04
#> 6       5 1.763333e-05 1.926667e-05 1.844990e-05
#> 7       6 1.333333e-07 1.666667e-07 7.151124e-08
```

### Explanation

The goal for speedup here was to vectorize each simulation replication. Note that `replicate` is *not* vectorized. It is essentially a wrapper for a `for` loop.

For repeatedly taking `n` samples from a fixed population without replacement, `RcppAlgos::permuteSample` will be faster than anything you can do with `replicate`.

A single `match` call over a matrix will be much faster than calling `intersect` on each row of the matrix if the `y` argument of `intersect` does not change. This works because all sampling is done without replacement. `match` needs to be followed up with a comparison for the no-matches, reshaping into a matrix, and then taking the row sums. All these operations are vectorized and will be very fast.

`tabulate` is faster than `table`, especially if you know the maximum integer in the data (as a bonus, calling tabulate this way will result in a vector whose length is equal to the `nbins` argument.

Finally, the speed difference between using integers and floats is going to be small, if anything (in fact, sometimes integer arithmetic is slower than float arithmetic due to checks that R has to perform). But with large datasets, integers are twice as memory-efficient.

Comment: Thank you, this is incredibly faster! I have a few questions:
1)permuteSample does the same thing as sample?
2)Is it more efficient to write an L when dealing with integer numbers? (i.e. 30L instead of L)
3)Why is this code way more effective than mine? By that I mean, why did you use the functions "tabulate, matrix, match and permuteSample" instead of "table, intersect and sample"?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two **base R** options that might speed up the simulations

```
f1 <- function() {
  rowSums(
    replicate(
      nr_esantion,
      {
        lucky <- sample(nr_49, 6, replace = FALSE)
        tabulate(
          colSums(matrix(replicate(es, sample(nr_49, 6)) %in% lucky, 6)),
          nbins = 7
        )
      }
    )
  )
}
```

or

```
f2 <- function() {
  rowSums(
    replicate(
      nr_esantion,
      tabulate(
        colSums(replicate(es, sample.int(49, 6)) <= 6),
        nbins = 7
      )
    )
  )
}
```

## Benchmark

Let `f0` denote the approach given by OP

```
f0 <- function() {
  table_1 <- rep(0, 7)
  table_1
  for (i in 1:nr_esantion)
  {
    lucky <- sample(nr_49, 6, replace = FALSE)
    inters <- replicate(es, length(intersect(sample(nr_49, 6, replace = FALSE), lucky)), simplify = "array")
    aux <- array(table(inters))
    # There are situations in which at one step "i", there are no intersections of cardinal 5 or 6.
    if (length(aux) == 5) {
      aux <- c(aux, 0, 0)
    } else {
      if (length(aux) == 6) {
        aux <- c(aux, 0)
      }
    }
    table_1 <- table_1 + aux
  }
}
```

and for simplicity, `nr_esantion <- 1` was used to see how much the speed is boosted in each single iteration

```
es <- 10^6
nr_49 <- 1:49
nr_esantion <- 1

microbenchmark(
  f0 = f0(),
  f1 = f1(),
  f2 = f2(),
  times = 10L,
  unit = "relative"
)
```

and we will see that

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f0 3.269589 3.445930 3.695388 3.623495 4.329602 3.040705    10
   f1 1.254187 1.270459 1.250016 1.306708 1.362433 0.901054    10
   f2 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(parallel)
nr_esantion <- 30
es <- 10^6
nr_49 <- 1:49

table_1 <- integer(7) # Initialize table with integer values for better performance

# Parallel processing setup
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) # Leave one core free for system processes
clusterExport(cl, varlist = c("nr_49", "es")) # Export variables to each node
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(methods)}) # Load any required packages on each node

system.time({
  # Use parSapply for parallel computation
  results <- parSapply(cl, 1:nr_esantion, function(x) {
    # Generate a new set of tickets and a lucky ticket for each iteration
    lucky_ticket <- sample(nr_49, 6, replace = FALSE)
    all_tickets <- matrix(sample(nr_49, es * 6, replace = TRUE), ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
    
    # Calculate the intersections
    intersections <- apply(all_tickets, 1, function(ticket) {
      length(intersect(ticket, lucky_ticket))
    })
    
    # Tabulate the results
    tabulate(intersections + 1, nbins = 7)
  })
  
  stopCluster(cl) # Stop the cluster after computation is done
})

table_1 <- colSums(results) / nr_esantion
table_1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I need to generate new "all_tickets" and "lucky_ticket" at every iteration, so each column of "results" is different.